# shell script, where is directory of file created?

Tags: unix

I have been a windows user and have just gotten into the unix (/ real) world.

In shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/tmp/query-api-test-data.txt
echo "{ \"index\" : { \"_index\" : \"cdr_${DATE}\", \"_type\" : \"xdr\" } }" >> $FILE
```

My question is where in windows can i find this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote file localization at this line:

```
FILE=/tmp/query-api-test-data.txt
```

It means you can find the file here:

```
/tmp/query-api-test-data.txt
```

But as it is in /tmp folder, it is not supposed to be a file that you would use, so it may be deleted after your script.